# Synchronous execution of Google Apps Script Webhook using Lock Service

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks, lock-service

I have a webhook where the script writes to spreadsheet.
When there are multiple incoming requests the data is overwritten to the same sheet row and it appears the spreadsheet dont collect all data since its overwriting

**

***I want a sequential execution where the incoming requests need to wait until the previous request has finished completing one after the other***

**

I have tried with

```
function doGet(e) {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    try {
        lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
    } catch (e) {
        ;
    }
    Utilities.sleep(20000)
    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("SHEET_URL")
        .getSheets()[0].appendRow([e.parameter.script]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: `LockService` should make your executions sequential. Please be specific what your problem is.0

Comment: No that doesnt work with my above code, when 10 concurrent request arrive they get overwritten

Comment: It lock service works then I wouldnt have posted the question here. There must be someting wrong in my code or something wrong with Google. The later cannot be.,

Comment: You are not placing your executions in the right place, please see my code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doGet(e) {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    try {
        lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed

    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("SHEET_URL")
        .getSheets()[0].appendRow([e.parameter.script]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    } catch (e) {
        
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
}
```